# Show Pods sources on the dashboard

Tags: kubernetes

My software has a dashboard and there is system information (CPU, Ram, Disk). But in kubernetes pods completely Worker resources appear. How should my approach be here? As far as I researched, pods not has its assigned resources.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways please check based on your preference:

You can use this way by [k9s](https://github.com/derailed/k9s) which is very easy way to check all the details.
Or if you want to check them manually

Go to pod's exec mode `kubectl exec -it pod_name -n namespace -- /bin/bash`

Run `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu/cpuacct.usage for cpu usage`

Run `cat /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/memory.usage_in_bytes for memory usage`
or

Deploying the dashboard is not default you can get by below command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.7.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
```

Use `kubectl proxy` to enable access to the dashboard and it will be available in the following [link](http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/.) and it will be accessed from the machine where you have executed the command. For more details please check this [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/web-ui-dashboard/).

Comment: But i have a my own app and own dashboard. I cannot use the kubernetes dashboard